# Count all apples and good apples

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, countif

On Google Sheet, I currently have a cell that looks like this as a "raw" table:

RAW:

```
Week Starting   Date    Apple type
12/31/2017  1/4/2018    Green
12/31/2017  1/5/2018    Green
1/7/2018    1/8/2018    Bad - Green
1/7/2018    1/8/2018    Bad - Green
1/7/2018    1/8/2018    Yellow
1/7/2018    1/9/2018    Green
1/7/2018    1/9/2018    Red
1/7/2018    1/9/2018    Red
1/7/2018    1/10/2018   Green
1/7/2018    1/10/2018   Yellow
1/7/2018    1/10/2018   Bad - Yellow
1/7/2018    1/12/2018   Yellow
1/14/2018   1/16/2018   Red
1/14/2018   1/16/2018   Yellow
1/21/2018   1/23/2018   Red
1/21/2018   1/23/2018   Bad - Red
1/21/2018   1/23/2018   Yellow
```

and I would like to write formula that returns something that looks like this:
Summary:

```
Week Starting   Count of all apples Count of only good apples
12/31/17                   2                  2
1/7/18                     10                 7
1/14/18                    2                  2
1/21/18                    3                  2
```

I've tried multiple countifs with a combination of minus, quotes, etc, but still couldn't get to this. Would someone please give me some tips around this? :/

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

G2: `=COUNTIF(A2:A18,F2)`
H2: `=G2-COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$18,F2,$C$2:$C$18,"*Bad*")`

[image]

These formulas will also work in Google Sheets

Answer (score 1):

For [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets):

`=QUERY(FILTER({{A:B},{C1;IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,"Bad"),"Good")}},A:A<>""),"select Col1, Count(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3", 1)`

It is a single-formula solution, the result is table:

```
Week Starting   Bad Good
12/31/2017            2
1/7/2018          3   7
1/14/2018             2
1/21/2018         1   2
```